# Prove or disprove $a^{\varphi(m)}=a^{k\,\varphi(m)}\pmod{m}$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove or disprove that $a^{\varphi(m)}=a^{k\,\varphi(m)}\pmod m$ where $\varphi(m)$ is the totient function, and $k\ge1$.

This is clearly true when $\gcd(a,m)=1$ since both sides are $1$ due to Euler's Theorem. I'm interested in the case where $\gcd(a,m)\neq1$.

I bet this is a two-liner using group theory but unfortunately I know nothing about group theory yet :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed true.

Write $m = p_1^{e_1} \cdots p_t^{e_t}$ in its prime factorization. It suffices to show that $a^{\phi(m)} = a^{ k \phi(m)}$ holds modulo $p_i^{e_i}$ for all $i$. It is easy to prove that $\phi(m) = p_1^{e_1-1}(p_1-1) \cdots p_t^{e_t-1}(p_t-1) \geq e_i$, so if $p_i \mid a$ this equation reads $0 \equiv 0 \mod p_i^{e_i}$. If $p_i \nmid a$ it reads $1 \equiv 1 \mod p_i^{e_i}$ because $\phi(p_i^{e_i}) \mid \phi(m)$ and $a^{\phi(p_i^{e_i})} \equiv 1 \mod p_i^{e_i}$.

Comment: Thanks, that was a clean explanation :)